# How to change the particular row colour of listview

Tags: android, listview

I have Listview of notification ,i want if user click on notification(particular row) its color should be change.
changing the color means notification was read.
the changed color should be reflect even if the app restarts.

For this i have write the code in a class extending array adapter.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View mView = v ;
    if(mView == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }
    listView=(ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.notiID);
    String sd= yORn.get(position);
    if(sd=="Y"){
        listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

i have also used the debugger and i am getting condition in if loop true, but my problem is that i am not getting the changed color for the lisview.
debugger is not moving in the if loop.

any ideas?

Comment: do not compare string by using `=` operator. use `equals()` instead.

Comment: Judging from your `getView()` method, you first need to learn how to use `ListView`. Please watch this first https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a RecyclerView instead of a Listview to start off with. In the Adapter for your RecyclerView check the position in the onBindViewHolder and set the background colour of the row accordingly. See below.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(position == 2){
        holder.ll_item_background.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.calc_boxes));
    } 

    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this by default I have given the background color as red and if the user reads then the background color will be changed to green as you expect. I have edited you code.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View mView = v ;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(mView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
            holder.listItem = mView;
            mView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)mView.getTag();
         }

        //By Default
        holder.listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        String sd= yORn.get(position);
        if(sd.equals("Y")){
            holder.listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        }

    class ViewHolder{
         View listItem;
    }
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View mView = v ;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(mView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(id, null);
            holder.listItem = mView;
            mView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)mView.getTag();
         }
        String sd= yORn.get(position);
        if(sd.equals("Y")){
            holder.listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

    }
    class ViewHolder{
         View listItem;
    }
```

Comment: @Selvin yes. you are right.. I just edit the ans. thanks for correction.

Comment: still wrong - what if the view is reused - obviously backroung will be green even if it shouldn't

Comment: @Selvin did not get what exactly you are saying.?? ...'view is reuse'.? what it means?

Comment: watch video posted by M-WaJeEh ... view is reused == (convertView!= null)

Comment: @Selvin see the ans now :)

Comment: **what if the view is reused - obviously backroung will be green even if it shouldn't** ... viewholder changes nothing here ...

Comment: @Selvin i thinks now the ans is correct.. correct me if i am wrong.?

Comment: *correct me if i am wrong* You are wrong...if the view is reused - obviously backroung will be green even if it shouldn't